# Who feeds New Crobuzon?

Tags: china-mieville, bas-lag

[China Miéville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Mi%C3%A9ville)'s [*Bas-Lag*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Lag) novels ([*Perdido Street Station*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perdido_Street_Station), [*The Scar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scar), [*Iron Council*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Council)) is fantasy with realistic political and economic structures. So I don't expect the city of [New Crobuzon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Crobuzon) to be isolated: its food has to be grown somewhere.

Yet after reading *Perdido Street Station*, I was left with the impression that the city was practically in the middle of a desert. Notice how the train lines don't expand beyond the boundaries of the city. (This is quite unlike the 19th century London that New Crobuzon is partly modeled upon.) This is touched on briefly in *The Scar* (chapter 1): ([extract found online](http://www.worldswithoutend.com/novel.asp?ID=60))

> This is the stubby end of the Grain Spiral, the long curl of farmland that feeds the city. Men and women can be seen among the crops, or plowing the black earth, or burning the stubbledepending on the season. Barges putter weirdly between fields, on canals hidden by banks of earth and vegetation. They go endlessly between the metropolis and the estates.

What are the political structures in the Grain Spiral? Who owns these estates? What about the other towns in the region? How come the New Crobuzon government doesn't seem to control the surrounding countryside? In short, what is the relationship between New Crobuzon and the people who feed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the political structures in the Grain Spiral? Who owns these estates?

It's not specifically discussed who has ownership or political control of the Grain Spiral. From what little we see in the books, it is rather anarchic and little policed, but so are large parts of New Crobuzon itself.

We can make some logical deductions, given that the ruling elite of New Crobuzon are both greedy and ruthlessly pragmatic. There is no rival power nearby to *prevent* them maintaining military and economic control of the Spiral, and a reliable food supply is crucial to the stability of the city, so we can assume NC's rulers have taken steps to keep control of the Spiral.

Instead of Victorian London, a better model here might be ancient Rome. Much of Italy was organised into vast agricultural estates known as [latifundia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latifundium#Ancient_Rome). These estates were owned by a small number of wealthy Romans, including the Emperor and leading senators. Rome was fed by the produce of the latifundia, along with fish, and grain imported by sea.

Like Rome and London, NC has easy access to the sea, so it is likely that fish and imported food are a significant part of the local diet.

> Notice how the train lines don't expand beyond the boundaries of the city.

New Crobuzon did try extending railways beyond the city boundaries, in *Iron Council*. The results were... interesting.

Victorian Britain was a different case: Multiple cities, and the land between them, were all under the control of a reasonably effective government which could guarantee security, and collect taxes on the profits. As we see in *Iron Council*, building a railway from New Crobuzon to its external trading partners is far more difficult.

One could imagine a system of purely local railways to move agricultural produce from the Spiral into the city; but for some combination of political and economic reasons, this hasn't happened, and they rely on the system of canals.

Comment: Well, the latifunda wasn't really enough; Rome depended on grain from North Africa past a certain point.

Answer (score 4):

New Crobuzon *is* a coastal city a few miles from the shore of the Swollen Ocean. As seen in *The Scar* there is an active, international, and sometimes autonomous fleet upon that ocean, implying *fishers* (e.g., the fishing port Qé Banssa) and possibly implying the harvest of *seaweeds*. In addition, the [vodyanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vodyanoy), being an amphibious, perhaps even more partial to the water than to the land, sub-populace of New Crobuzon *may* have better ability to cultivate, hunt or gather from regional rivers and lakes than humans.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think there's an answer to this. I generally refer to the cityscapes he creates as "not ecologically viable". As in, his cities are narratively breathtaking, but a little hard to digest as functioning urban systems.

Comment: It's weird how our perceptions differ. I find his world generally realistic, both politically and economically, which is why this point bothers me (whereas I don't care who feeds Coruscant or Gondor).

Comment: There's a lot of detail that Mieville leaves out of the books - mostly because it's not very interesting or relevant to the story. The author's style is to include amazing amounts of detail about his rickety, just-grew-that-way cities and political structures, but all of it very targeted to creating the exact mood he's going for. Learning the economics and politics of how food is purchased, stored, taxed, and so on isn't relevant to any of the Bas-Lag books.... that is, the books so far.

Comment: (And whether there will be more is quite [uncertain](http://www.theliteraryplatform.com/2011/03/return-to-bas-lag-an-interview-with-china-mieville/).)